# Run node js file using java in the background process

Tags: java

Currently, I am developing an automation script, Where I need to run a node js file using the command line, and it basically generates a simulator virtually.

I want to run the simulator using the background process which should handle by java code.

Currently, I have written a code that opens a terminal by popup and executes the node js file automatically. But I want to make this process run in the background. Also, I think this code has a dependency on Windows os. I want to run the process in the background and it should run also in Linux operating system

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]
                {"cmd", "/k", "start", "cmd", "/c", "\"cd 6edb792f1492/Simulator && node device.js & pause\""});

    }
```

**Is there anyone who can help me to run the process in the background using java code??**

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Nashorn`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nashorn_(JavaScript_engine)).

Below is a raw example to run Javascript code from Java.

```
public class NashornExample {  
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{  
        // Creating script engine  
        ScriptEngine ee = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("Nashorn");  
        // Reading Nashorn file  
        ee.eval(new FileReader("js/hello.js"));  
    }  
}
```

**NOTE:** Nashorn has been **deprecated** from JDK15 onward.

You can use a Runnable to run your Javascript in a new thread. Try something like this.

```
Runnable runnable = () -> {
    //YOUR CODE RUNNING JAVASCRIPT HERE
};      
    
Thread thread1 = new Thread(runnable);
thread1.start();
```

Taken from [this](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-nashorn) tutorial.